# Putting an image gallery over a back ground image

Tags: html, css, image, background

On my homepage I have a background image and I want to overlay that background image with an image gallery (4 images) placed in the center. I have attached a [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lho3p.jpg) to give people an idea.

Thanks

Comment: Is the image what you want or what you have? Can you include your current code?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```js
document.getElementById('g1').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('bigImage').innerHTML = '<img src="http://www.kurzweilai.net/images/Naam-Limits-of-Earth-Part1-001-earth-600x600.jpg" style="height: 600px; width: 600px;">';
  document.getElementById('g1').innerHTML = '<img src="http://www.spitzer.caltech.edu/uploaded_files/images/0009/6502/ssc2013-07b_Ti.jpg" style="height: 60px; width: 60px;">';
};
```

```css
#bigImage{
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
}
#gallery {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  z-index: 99999;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id = "bigImage">
    <img src="http://www.spitzer.caltech.edu/uploaded_files/images/0009/6502/ssc2013-07b_Ti.jpg" style="height: 600px; width: 600px;">
  </div>
  <div id = "gallery">
    <div id = "g1">
      <img src="http://www.kurzweilai.net/images/Naam-Limits-of-Earth-Part1-001-earth-600x600.jpg" style="height: 60px; width: 60px;">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or like this, by using the position property...

```css
#bigImage{
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  background-image: url("http://www.spitzer.caltech.edu/uploaded_files/images/0009/6502/ssc2013-07b_Ti.jpg");
}
#gallery {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  z-index: 99999;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id = "bigImage">
  <div id = "gallery">
      <img src="http://www.kurzweilai.net/images/Naam-Limits-of-Earth-Part1-001-earth-600x600.jpg" style="height: 60px; width: 60px;">
    </div>
</div>
```